# Having trouble with compiling linear search function in C

Tags: c

I have a linear searcher function that prints out where a certain number is in an array and if it isn't found it should return " Nothing found". However, it seems to print both where it is located and and it isn't found as well. I was wondering where I had the error? Thanks!

```
void searcher(int *array, int n, int key){

     for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       if(array[i] == key){

         printf(" %d is present at location %d.\n", key, i+1);
         break;
       }

     }
     if( i == 0)
       printf(" %d is not present in the array.\n", key);


}
```

Comment: Note: if you fix the problem with `i`'s scope pointed out by `jschultz410`, this still won't work (unless the array is empty) because `i` won't be 0.

Comment: Even if I made it so it reads an array before it does the search? Like this :

       readArray(input, count);
      searcher( input, count, key);

Comment: @JBo , Just remove the last `if` and use `return;` instead of `break;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you declare an `i` in your loop scope, so the `i` you use inside the loop is a different `i` than the one you use outside the loop.  You almost surely have a global or static named `i`, which is a really bad naming practice, that happens to have the value 0.

Also, even if you declare `i` at function scope, your code as written will not print "is not present in the array" unless n <= 0 because your test for that print is incorrect.  For a similar reason, it will print out both options if the first element happens to match when n > 0.  That is because you break the loop before incrementing `i` on a match.

You could rewrite it like this:

```
void searcher(int *array, int n, int key)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n && array[i] != key; ++i);

  if (i < n)
    printf(" %d is present at index %d.\n", key, i);
  else
    printf(" %d is not present in the array.\n", key);
}
```

Comment: I got it to work on my code! Thanks I didn't know this was another way to write it! I'd like to say thanks to you again, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Well the question already has an answer which is very well explained, but here is my approach slightly different from jschultz.

```
void searcher(int *array, int n, int key)
{
  int flag=1;
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       if(array[i] == key){
         flag=0;
         printf(" %d is present at location %d.\n", key, i+1);
         break;
       }
      }
     if(flag)
       printf(" %d is not present in the array.\n", key);
}
```